# Detect string encoding in php4

Tags: php, character-encoding

How I can detect string encoding without mb_* and iconv functions in php4

Comment: ...why do you want to detect encoding without using any of the encoding functions?

Comment: because it is not standard php4 functions and it not present on every server wit php4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, wouldn't you just use the function:

```
/* Detect character encoding with current detect_order */
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);

/* "auto" is expanded to "ASCII,JIS,UTF-8,EUC-JP,SJIS" */
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, "auto");

/* Specify encoding_list character encoding by comma separated list */
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, "JIS, eucjp-win, sjis-win");
```

As described in the [PHP.net manua](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)l?